# error in angular and firebase data retrival

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

this is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html', 
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  student: Observable<student[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase ) {
    this.student = db.list('/student').valueChanges();
    console.log(this.student);
  }
}
```

it is showing error that cannot find name 'student'

[image: this the picture of the database]

Answer (score 0):

Its look like you wrote the DB path not as expected.
Try to change `this.student = db.list('/student').valueChanges();` to:

`this.student = db.list('/regestration-student/student').valueChanges();`
if its the hierarchy of the db object.

If `regestration-student` is the DB name, so it sound like you not register properly to the DB.

Another option is: The line `student: Observable<student[]>;`
Im not sure about that. where you declared the `student`?
You should try some thing like `FirebaseListObservable<any[]>` or `Observable<any[]>`